# How to reduce sparsity with df.get_dummies() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lest suppose that I have a following Data-frame

```
   userID   product_id
0     1    a   
1     2    s
2     1    d 
3     1    f
```

Now if I do `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['product_id'])`  then I get the following result

```
  userID   product_id_a product_id_s product_id_d product_id_f
0     1    1            0             0            0
1     2    0            1             0            0
2     1    0            0             1            0
3     1    0            0             0            1
```

as there are just 2 unique user id's so instead I want the following result

```
  userID product_id_a product_id_s product_id_d product_id_f
0     1    1            0             1            1
1     2    0            1             0            0
```

so that the Data-frame will be more meaningful and less sparse, can anyone please help me in getting the result. Data set is in billions of record so some efficient query will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `user id`, then use [str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies)

```
res = df.groupby("userID").agg(",".join)



 (res
.product_id.str.get_dummies(",")
.add_prefix("product_id_")
.reset_index())

        userID       product_id_a   product_id_d    product_id_f    product_id_s
   0       1                1              1             1           0
   1       2                0              0             0           1
```

Comment: if you look at the output of get_dummies then there is no duplicates. so it is not doing anything, producing the same result as get_dummies.

Answer (score 1):

We need to understand the function of get_dummies() first to get to the solution. This function converts categorical variable into an indicator variable (basically sparse one hot encoding). You'll get more details on this link:- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html.

As I see you want to encode the userID. However, in the code you ended up encoding the second column. Your correct code will be as given below:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['userID'])
```

Regarding efficiency, if you want more efficient query then do not use One Hot Coding technique of get_dummies(). Rather, use Label Encoding, which encodes each unique column value to an integer. Label encoding is faster and computationally less expensive for large categorical values. A sample code using label encoding is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
#Creating the dataframe as shown by you in your example
data =[['x1','a'],['x2','b'],['x1','d'],['x1','f']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['userID','product_id'])
# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
df['userID']= df['userID'].astype('category')
df['userID'] = df['userID'].cat.codes
df

 userID product_id
0   0   a
1   1   b
2   0   d
3   0   f
```

By the way, for userID column you do not need Label encoding if the userIDs are unique integers. However, I assume you are giving an example and the actual problem may have large alphanumeric values as userID.
I think I have been able to convey the point to you. For more details you may refer to this article on encoding: -
https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd

Thanks

Comment: but if I want to convert products name into feature then I would need one hot encoding, because this way will not help, will it?

Comment: No. I suggest that you do not use one hot encoding. Use label encoding on product_id. Use it the same way as it has been used on user ID.

Comment: ok I understand, let me give a little insight, I want to learn the user behavior based on the products he purchased or viewed, now instead of scatter data, I want the data on user level and then check which segment of product effect user the most. it is just an example though.

Comment: Your requirement will work perfectly well with label encoding of ' product-id'. 'userID' need not be encoded if it is already an unique integer (If alphanumeric then you may encode)

Comment: I would like to reiterate that we encode categorical values in machine learning because machine learning algorithms can handle only numerical values, and not texts/alphanumeric values. Thus, encode only when required. Also, avoid sparse encoding techniques like One Hot Encoding for large datasets.